# How to calculate dPermissiions parameter in the Ghostscript command line?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I am looking for an online calculator, a tool or at least an understandable article, which lets me define the value of `dPermissiions` parameter of Ghostscript command line.
Please, advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its documented in the VectorDevices.htm, where it says its a bit field and directs you to the PDF Reference Manual. The actual values are defined by Adobe.

The various access permissions are described under the Standard Security Handler (on p121 of the 1.7 PDF Reference) and the individual bits are described in Table 3.20 (p124 and 124 in the 1.7 PDF Reference Manual).

Bits 1 and 2 (the lowest 2 bits) are always defined as 0, as (currently) are bits 13-32. Bits 7 & 8, annoyingly are reserved and must be 1.

So lets say you want to grant permission to print the document, to do that you need to set bit 3. So bits 1-2 are 0 and bits 4-32 are also 0, bits 7 and 8 must be 1. In binary that corresponds to:

00000000 00000000 00000000 11000100

Which in hex is 00 00 00 C4 which in decimal is 196. So you would set -dPermissions=196

To take a more complex example, we might also want to set bit 12 to allow a high quality print (for revision 3 or better of the security handler). Now we want to set bits 3 and 12, in binary:

00000000 00000000 00001000 11000100

in hex 00 00 08 C4 which is decimal 2244 so you would set -dPermissions=2244

The Windows calculator, when set to programmer mode, has a binary entry configuration. If you enter the bitfield in binary, and then switch to decimal it'll convert it for you. Alternatively there's an online conversion tool [here](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/binary-to-decimal.html).

Just write out the bits you want set as binary, set bits 7 & 8, then convert to decimal, simples!

**--EDIT--**

So as Vsevolod Azovsky pointed out, the bits 12-32 should be 1. Using the same tool I pointed at above you can get the decimal signed 2's complement of the binary representation, which you can use as the value for Permissions.

However, if you do that, then Ghostscript's pdfwrite device will produce a warning. The reason is that some of the bits I've set above (anything above bit 8) are only compatible with the revision 3 (or better) security handler, and the default for pdfwrite is to use the revision 2 security encryption.

So if you want to use the bits marked in the Adobe documentation as 'revision 3' then you (obviously) need to set the revision to 3 using `-dEncryptionR=3`. This requires that the output PDF file be a 1.4 or greater file, you can't use revision 3 with a PDF 1.3 file.

Note that for the revision 2 security handler all the bits 1-2 and 7-32 must be 1.

Hopefully that also answers the questions in the last comment.

Comment: However I was much confused, treing to set bits 12-32 to 1 and getting wrong parameters ((( Is that a manual lack?

Comment: Hmm does the reference say they should be 1 ? I thought they were supposed to be 0, let me check..... Hmm yes you are correct, they should be 1. Which will mean that you will end up with a negative number (because bit 32 is set). I'll try this out on Monday and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you, colleague! Yeah... And one more question then. I automate the setting permissions to a larg amount of PDF's. So as far as I see there are a Reviosion2 & Revision3 parameters. How critical are they? Is it a file or an application property? Unfortunately I cannot read 978 pages of PDF Manual at the nearest time (((,

Comment: the value for dPermissions can also be negative - so if you get an error try the 2-complement decimal representation of the binary number
(the calculator linked is capable of showing the negative decimal for a 2-complement binary)